# First function call success, second call fails. (Solidity with Hardhat)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I've been trying to store 10000 16byte strings (the string that I used is 'abcdefghijklmnop') in a solidity mapping: mapping(uint256 => string)

1. I've tried sending all 10000 strings in one transaction and it always exceeds the maximum gas limit and fails.
2. Divided those 10000 strings into equal 10 arrays and tried to do 10 transactions.. The first transaction, with the first 1000 strings happens successfully but the following transactions fail due to a gas issue

Solidity Code:

```
uint256 public totalGenomes;
mapping(uint256 => string) public genomesList;

function addGenome(string[] memory genome) public {
        for (uint256 index = totalGenomes; index < (1000 + totalGenomes); index++) {
            genomesList[index] = genome[index];
        }
        totalGenomes += 1000;
    }
```

Hardhat script: there are 10 files genomes0.txt, genomes1.txt, genomes2.txt .... each containing 1000 lines of  'abcdefghijklmnop'

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let filepath = `./img/genomes${i}.txt`;
        let genomes1000 = [];
        genomes1000 = fs.readFileSync(filepath).toString().split('\n');
        console.log(filepath);
        await svgNFT.addGenome(genomes1000);
    }
```

Error:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit
```

I also intend to minimise the gas price for the whole process.
Have anyone here got prior experience on such a scenario?

---

**UPDATE:** I got past the above problem.

I did this suggested by **Miguel_LZPF** on Hardhat discord:

```
contract.function(param1, param2..., lastfunctionparam, {gasLimit: xxxxx})
```

and define the gasLimit and gasPrice manually. And now, I'm stuck in another problem.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x11740C2367a0F0465d31b3612B3A5464dC7c8Afb

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution
> reverted]

Still the first transaction in the loop happens to be successful the rest fails.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the code producing the failing transaction.

Comment: Edited and updated :) please help if possible